How to make `flutter analyze` treat Info as errors in VSCode
When using the flutter analyze command without the --no-fatal-infos option, it treats info-level issues as errors, resulting in an exit status of 1 if any info issues are present.
However, in VSCode, these info issues are displayed with a blue wavy underline, making them easy to overlook. Is there a method to configure VSCode or flutter analyze so that info-level issues are highlighted as errors? Or is it generally advisable to avoid such a practice?


You can set individual rules to be treated as errors, but I'm not aware of way to treat all rules as errors. https://dart.dev/tools/analysis#changing-the-severity-of-rules

Thank you!
When I added some_info_rule: true in analysis_options.yaml, it didn’t change anything. I believe it’s not possible to modify the effects of a rule that’s already enabled. It seems the only option for managing an enabled rule is to disable it...

No, as shown by the document I linked to, you can do some_info_rule: error to treat it as an error.

I was mistaken. Thank you, that worked well!
